# Digital clock doesn't update

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I'm trying to integrate a Digital Clock in a label, in a FXML controller, but it doesnt work, it doesnt'update, only show the original text of the label ( dunno )

Fxml:

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="320.0" prefWidth="480.0" style="-fx-background-color: SteelBlue;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="simulazione.esame.ControllerPannello">
    <children>
      <Label fx:id="orario" layoutX="32.0" layoutY="65.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="247.0" text="dunno" />
      <ChoiceBox fx:id="settimana" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="116.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
      <Label layoutX="195.0" layoutY="108.0" text="Stato Impianto" />
      <RadioButton fx:id="onRadio" layoutX="207.0" layoutY="129.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="on" />
      <RadioButton fx:id="offRadio" layoutX="263.0" layoutY="129.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="off" />
      <AnchorPane layoutX="181.0" layoutY="180.0" prefHeight="135.0" prefWidth="289.0">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="23.0" text="Temp per raffreddamento" />
            <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="74.0" text="Temp per riscaldamento" />
            <TextField layoutX="176.0" layoutY="19.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="79.0" />
            <TextField layoutX="176.0" layoutY="70.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="79.0" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>

    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Fxml controller:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 *
 * @author Antonio
 */
public class ControllerPannello implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox settimana;
    @FXML
    private Label orario, boh;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton onRadio, offRadio;

    private ObservableList<String> sett = 
            FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList("Lunedì", "Martedì", "Mercoledì",
                 "Giovedì", "Venerdì", "Sabato", "Domenica");   
    ToggleGroup stato = new ToggleGroup();

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
        onRadio.setToggleGroup(stato);
        offRadio.setToggleGroup(stato);
        settimana.setItems(sett);

        orario = new DigitalClock();




    }    

}
```

DigitalClock.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.util.Calendar;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



class DigitalClock extends Label {
  public DigitalClock() {
    bindToTime();
  }

  // the digital clock updates once a second.
public void bindToTime() {
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
      new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0),
        new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
          @Override public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
            String hourString = StringUtilities.pad(2, ' ', time.get(Calendar.HOUR) == 0 ? "12" : time.get(Calendar.HOUR) + "");
            String minuteString = StringUtilities.pad(2, '0', time.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + "");
            String secondString = StringUtilities.pad(2, '0', time.get(Calendar.SECOND) + "");
            String ampmString = time.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM ? "AM" : "PM";
            setText(hourString + ":" + minuteString + ":" + secondString + " " + ampmString);
          }
        }
      ),
      new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1))
    );
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();
  }
}

class StringUtilities {
  /**
   * Creates a string left padded to the specified width with the supplied padding character.
   * @param fieldWidth the length of the resultant padded string.
   * @param padChar a character to use for padding the string.
   * @param s the string to be padded.
   * @return the padded string.
   */
  public static String pad(int fieldWidth, char padChar, String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = s.length(); i < fieldWidth; i++) {
      sb.append(padChar);
    }
    sb.append(s);

    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried it myself, and it works fine :/

Comment: I would add that if you're using java-8 you can replace your ```EventHandler``` with: ```ae -> setText(LocalTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss a")))```

Comment: Dunno, seems like that it isn't able to pass the class to lable

orario = new DigitalClock();

Comment: I Just added a ```DigitalClock``` to a ```StackPane``` and added it to an empty scene, and it works.

Comment: You could try binding the label's text property to that of the clock: ```orario.textProperty().bind(new DigitalClock().textProperty());```. But I'm not sure if it's going to work with FXML.

Comment: Wow it works with  orario.textProperty().bind(new DigitalClock().textProperty());

Thank you!

Comment: Also have a look at the Medusa library. Maybe you can reuse a clock from there: https://github.com/HanSolo/Medusa